# Facebook Payments Item lookup returns error null

Tags: facebook, payment

So I have new open graph payment object:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head prefix=
    "og: http://ogp.me/ns#
     fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#
     product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
    <meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
    <meta property="og:title"                  content="My awesome product" />
    <meta property="og:image"                  content="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" />
    <meta property="og:url"                    content="https://my_awesome_url" />
    <meta property="og:description"            content="Description" />
    <meta property="product:price:amount"      content="1.00"/>
    <meta property="product:price:currency"    content="LVL"/>
 </head>
</html>
```

And from calling:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'pay',
      action: 'purchaseitem',
      product: 'https://my_awesome_url',
    },
    function (data) {console.log(data)}
);
```

All I get is

> Something went wrong while processing your payment. You haven't been
>   charged for this transaction, so please try again.

and data in callback - `null`

I can't wrap my head around what is wrong with it. Debugging using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug loads up the object just fine and event after loading via debug and when calling this item from cache it still fails on something and keeps it silent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've hit a bug. More on here https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/206338606188153?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5230b1244ad598832999012